# names server change DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system

After i changed the naes server from squarespace to google cloud dns i got following error
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

what i did wrong that i get this error.

i tried to insert the server wit dot on the end and without.

[squarespace nameserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NUZo.png)

[google cloud dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHq5P.png)

Comment: There appear to be DNSSEC issues with your domain - https://dnsviz.net/d/world-of-easy-decisions.com/dnssec/ - You might try disabling DNSSEC to see if that is indeed the issue https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/dnssec and then take appropriate steps to resolve that properly.

Comment: Thanks was the error i had to deactivate by squarespace the DNSSEC

Answer (score 2):

Already resolved via the comments.

---

According to https://dnsviz.net/d/world-of-easy-decisions.com/dnssec/ there appeared to be DNSSEC issues with your domain.

Consider  (temporarily) disabling DNSSEC to see if that resolves the issue.